# PHP Sessions are not working in some sites of a server

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm trying to set a session in a website which it's server includes 3 sites are using PHP Sessions without facing a problem.

The code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 13824000);
    session_set_cookie_params(13824000);
    session_start();
    ob_start();

    $currentTimeoutInSecs = ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
    echo 'Session ID: '.session_id().'<br>';
    echo 'Expire: '.$currentTimeoutInSecs.'<br>';
    echo 'Before: '.$_SESSION['test'].'<br>';
    $_SESSION['test'] = rand();
    echo 'After: '.$_SESSION['test'].'<br>';
?>
```

The output:

```
Session ID:
Expire: 13824000
Before:
After: 1750678048
```

Everytime I reload the page, I see that bot `Session ID` and `Before` empty!

The server settings looks great because it's working well with the other websites which having the same VHost configurations.

Note: I also tried to regenerate the Session ID after starting the session but nothing changed.

Best regards.

Comment: Check your PHP log for "Headers already sent" warnings, and fix the cause.

Comment: @Barmar, The only thing I see in the PHP logs is `Warning: Undefined array key "test" in /home/testsite/test.php on line 16`.

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem Solved!

I just changed the `session.save_path` at `/etc/php-fpm.d/testsite.com.conf` to `/tmp` instead of `/var/lib/php/session`.